# Desktop app screen turns white with electron+angular2?

Tags: node.js, angular, web, electron

I made a desktop application by angular2 and electron.There is no problem usually,but sometimes,the screen will turn white,and console show `devtools was disconnected from the page...`.
I guess the process is stuck.But I can't find what's the cause of all this?
Could you help me ?

```js
//this is my main.js(Main process)

/**
 * Created by sjq on 16-11-1.
 */
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const ipcMain = electron.ipcMain


// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
var mainWindow

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 800,
        resizable: false,
        frame: false
    })

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

    // Open the DevTools.
    //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null;
    });


    ipcMain.on('export', function (event, arg) {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("export_video", arg)
    })
    ipcMain.on('entry', function (event, arg) {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("entry_video", arg)
    })
    ipcMain.on('stop_video', function (event, arg) {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("stop_video", arg)
    })
    ipcMain.on('f12', function () {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    })
    ipcMain.on('close', function () {
        app.quit();
    })

}
mainWindow.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
        // Handle the error
        console.log(error)
    })


// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);


// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.

    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

if (process.platform == 'win32')
    process.env['VLC_PLUGIN_PATH'] = require('path').join(__dirname, 'node_modules/webchimera.js/plugins');



//触发闪退
//setTimeout(function () {
//    process.crash();
//},5000)




// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Comment: This can often happen during long operations and especially infinite loops. Do any of these happen in your application anywhere?

Comment: I used `setInterval` in many places.Because I need to send a http request every second to get message and show it on the page.But there was no white screen in November，it only happened in the latest week.

Comment: @Zenny When the screen turned white, I found a process dead.